# Update the reference from Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1, version 1.0.9651.0 to version 1.0.9651.40228

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, winjs, project-reference

I was building/deploying my Windows Phone app in Visual Studio Professional 2013 with Update 3. The following console output showed up:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CapturingVideos, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
2>------ Deploy started: Project: CapturingVideos, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
2>Deploying to Phone Internal Storage...
2>Creating a new clean layout...
2>Copying files: Total <1 mb to layout...
2>Checking whether required frameworks are installed...
2>Warning : DEP0810 : This app references Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1, version 
1.0.9651.0, found in your SDK, but you have a higher version of 
Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1 installed on the target machine, 1.0.9651.40228. If you 
continue to run this application, it will run against the currently installed version,  
Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1, version 1.0.9651.40228. Consider updating your SDK to match     
the version of Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1 that is installed. 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260891
2>Registering the application to run from layout...
```

I was curious about the Warning which suggested me to update the reference from WinJS.2.1 v1.0.9651.0 to v1.0.9651.40228. So I downloaded and installed the [Visual Studio 2013 Extensions for the Windows Library for JavaScript](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40793). After restarting the OS and VS 2013, I tried to create a new Windows Phone project from the blank template. I expected the References folder to contain Windows Library for JavaScript 2.1 v1.0.9651.40228. However, it still only point to the old version, which was v1.0.9651.0. Was I on the wrong track or did I miss something? Please point me to the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: suggest trying removing and adding reference to winjs lib in project

Comment: Hi Sushil, I was trying to do the same but didn't know where the newly installed WinJS lib resided. During the installation, I wasn't given any information about where it would be installed. Do you know how to find out the path to the new WinJS lib?

Comment: right click refences node in soln explorer-> add reference. it should show all installed extensions.

Comment: That doesn't work. The available extensions listed was still the old version.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by wrong App Package Version number which is clearly displayed as **1.0.9651.0** in the reference properties despite all the .js and .css files the package contains have the correct build number **1.0.9651.40228** specified in their headers.

The App Package Version property takes its value from package's manifest file `%Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1\1.0\SDKManifest.xml` particularly from the following line:

`FrameworkIdentity="Name=Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1, MinVersion=1.0.9651.0"`

So tick the file's Read-only flag off, open it as an administrator and change the MinVersion number. Reload your solution. The warning message should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found this blog post, along with your question here on StackOverflow:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lighthouse/archive/2014/04/21/can-t-update-visual-studio-2013-extensions-for-the-windows-library-for-javascript.aspx

I didn't have the issues your describing, or the issues warned about in the blog post, but they explained how to correct them with a powershell script.

Comment: I was following the instructions in the link but got stuck in the first step when running the following command:
get-msiproductinfo | where { $_.Name -like '*Windows Library for JavaScript*' }

I got the following error message:
get-msiproductinfo : The 'get-msiproductinfo' command was found in the
 module 'MSI', but the module could not be loaded. ...